# Embed pyplot In TKinter Window

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm building a GUI under tkinter and I need to plot EEG signals within my app page. After importing everything needed, I created the canvas as follows:

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

 def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
    label = tk.Label(self, text=("Time Representation"), font=LARGE_FONT)
    label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

    f = plt.figure()
    a = f.add_subplot(111)

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, self)
    toolbar.update()
    canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="plot",
                        command=lambda: time_plot())
    button1.pack()

    def time_plot()
```

The problem is that when I plot my data, another figure pops open and the page of my app appears with a blank graph.

Here's the ploting part of my function:

```
        def time_plot():
        ....
        a.set_xticks(np.arange(t_window))
        lines = LineCollection(segs, offsets=offsets, transOffset=None)
        a.add_collection(lines)

        a.set_yticks(ticklocs)
        a.set_yticklabels(ch_names)
        a.set_xlabel('Time (s)')

        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.show()

        canvas.draw()
```

As I'm new to both python and tkinter, I don't know where the problem is to make the plot appear within the app. I think that it is caused by the plt.show() but I don't know how to fix it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could finally solve it on my own. I have commented these two lines and my plot is appearing inside the canvas:

```
#plt.tight_layout()
#plt.show()
```